# Why is S/MIME (instead of PGP) recommended for such an scenario?

Tags: smime

A large MNC with approximately 50,000 employees, and with offices in Asia, Europe and North America. This MNC operates its own PKI environment, with a self-signed Certificate Authority based at its head quarters in North America and Registration authorities distributed across the regions. Non- repudiation needs to be enforced in secure email exchanges.

Comment: Are you doing homework?

Answer (score 3):

That's because of "*enforced*". PGP uses a [Web of Trust](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_of_trust) which is, by nature, decentralized. To enforce things, you need some hierarchical structure with a central point of decision, which X.509 provides (in this case, through the "self-signed CA at headquarters). In the PGP model, each user is the center of his own world and cannot be dictated his trust.

Answer (score 2):

Short version:

1. Certificates are based on validated trust and are more integrated into corporate mail systems
2. PGP is based on "claims of trust", and support is not as wide across corporate mail systems